# Alternative labels giving Fixed width constraints may cause clipping warning why?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have designed two labels side by side i have given left side label 150 fixed width, why alternatively getting below warning.

[image]

For above image left label i have given constant text and constraints like below

```
fixed width = 150, top = 10, leading = 10 , height = 30
```

for right label text will come from json and constraints like below

```
 top = 10, leading = 10, trailing = 10, height = 30
```

i have highlighted all my left side fixed width labels, here for all labels i got below warning

> Main.storyboard Fixed width constraints may cause clipping

but here if i select first label warning and if **give greater then or equal** and horizontal hugging from 251 to 250 then warning disappears.. like same if i do for second label then it becomes big like below
[image]

for third label if i give greater then or equal then warning disappears.. like alternatively warning disappears why, you can see that in top image. why its happening like this, how to clear all my warnings. please help me.

Comment: right label text you remove trailing constraint and add width constraint

Comment: @TanjimaKothiya, no, i can't give fixed width for right label bcoz its data will come from json, so i cant give as well as its width should vary accordingly iphone screen width

Comment: I have 40 warnings like this, please help me

Comment: you set horizontal spacing

Comment: @iPhoneDev did you try with my answer? It worked at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Give the left sided labels horizontal content hugging priority of 252.

2.Give the right sided labels horizontal content hugging priority of 251.

3.Give horizontal spacing of 8 between the left sided and right sided labels.

4.Remove fixed widths for all labels.

5.Align leading and trailing of all the left sided labels and just the trailing of all the right sided labels.

6.Give vertical space to left sided label from right sided label of the previous row.

7.Vertically center align the left sided and right sided label in the same row.

All your warnings will disappear.

Comment: thank you, i changed left sided labels horizontal content hugging priority of 252, and greater then or equal to width then its working.